# Are $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$ isomophic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

For localizationg of a ring in a prime number (noted p), I mean (that's how my book defines it) all the elements of the field of fractions of the ring in question of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ such that b can't be divided by p. In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$ and p, we are talking of {$\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that p doesn't divide b}.

With this in mind, are the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ in 2, $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$, and the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ in 3, $\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$, isomorphic? Can you explain well how?

I was thinking of proceeding using the ideals of these rings pˆn$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, I am not sure how, but they should be bilateral ideals and therefore the kernel of some homomorphism. I was thinking of using the universal property of the quotient or the correspondence theorem, but didn't get far. I would include more work, but it is almost non-existent.

Comment: Take $f$ a purported isomorphism of unital rings $\Bbb Z_{(2)}\to\Bbb Z_{(3)}$. By definition, $f(1)=1$. However, $1+1\notin\Bbb Z_{(2)}^*$ whereas $f(1+1)\in\Bbb Z_{(3)}^*$.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much. We never used purported isomorphisms, but this seems to be from $\mathbb{Z}$ to both the localizations, am I right?

Comment: "Purported" is not a techical term.

Comment: Purported isn't a fixed definition. @SassatelliGiulio's point was that *if* there were an isomorphism, it would map a non-unit to a unit, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There residue fields are not isomorphic, because of
$$
\Bbb Z_{(p)}/(p)\cong \Bbb F_p.
$$
Hence the $p$-local numbers are not isomorphic as rings for different primes.

Comment: Thanks. I would also like to ask you another question, but the site doesn't allow me for the moment (I am new) regarding whether if ℤ[]
 and the ring quotient ℤ[,](−2024)
 are isomophic, with ℤ[]
 being the ring of polynoms over ℤ
 (in variable t), and (xy - 2024) is an ideal.

Comment: Thank you, @DietrichBurde

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs). This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I can't conclude. I understand what is going on F_2 not being isomophic to F_3, but why does the fact that the quotient of Z_(2) by 2 Z_(2) is not isomorphic to the quotient of Z_(3) and 3 Z_(3) imply that Z_(2) is not isomorphic to Z_(3)?

Comment: You need to find out whether or not the residue field is "preserved" under an isomorphism of the two local rings. This is explained here at this site, and if you search you can find it (as Bill says, we don't want to add more dupe answers).

Comment: Thanks, I will look for it.